# Dynamic table names in pg-promise

Tags: pg-promise

I would like to dynamically select the table in a pg-promise query. The following code does not work, any help is appreciated!

```
return db.any('SELECT * from $1', table_name)
```

The error message I get is:

```
error:  error: syntax error at or near
```

I am not sure if I should be using a helper, as described in this link:
https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.TableName.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct approach is via [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names):

```js
await db.any('SELECT * from $1:name', [table]);
// or
await db.any('SELECT * from ${table:name}', {table});
```

And with the schema:

```js
await db.any('SELECT * from $1:name.$2:name', [schema, table]);
// or
await db.any('SELECT * from ${schema:name}.${table:name}', {schema, table});
```

A more generic approach is via [TableName](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.TableName.html):

```js
const tn = new pgp.helpers.TableName({schema, table});

await db.any('SELECT * from $1', [tn]);
// or
await db.any('SELECT * from ${tn}', {tn});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the below to work (2023):

const result = await db.any('SELECT * FROM $1:name', ['funtable']);
or

const result = await db.any('SELECT * FROM $1:name.$2:name', ['public','funtable'])

Where, "funtable" is a table name within the "public" schema. Basically, the table and schema names have to be in single quotes unless you are passing in a variable.